# Implementing tasks that can be canceled in Bolts Framework (BFTask)

Tags: ios, nsoperation, bolts-framework, bftask

`BFTask` has been good to me but I have one complaint: I've yet to see a working example of how you ought to `cancel` a task. The entirety of the documentation on the subject is found on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) with a single lowly section that includes everything but the part I care about: *how* to cancel the task.

```
// Somewhere else.
MYCancellationToken *cancellationToken = [[MYCancellationToken alloc] init];
[obj doSomethingComplicatedAsync:cancellationToken];

// When you get bored...
[cancellationToken cancel];
```

Their code snippet is followed by:

> Note: The cancellation token implementation should be thread-safe.

I am wondering the following:

1. Is there a good reason that they may not have provided the `cancel` method on the `BFTask` interface itself? They have a property representing whether the task was canceled but no means to cancel it.
2. Is there a good reason that they would not include a `cancellationToken(s)` property on the `BFTask` itself?
3. Is the implementation of `cancel` strongly coupled to the task itself? Or is a general implementation possible as in the case of `cancelAllOperations` of an `NSOperationQueue`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. As you might know, `BFTask` is an implementation of the [Future and Promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) construct:
   "a future is a read-only placeholder view of a variable, while a promise is a writable, single assignment container which sets the value of the future".
   Basically, a `BFTask` is a `Future`: it is a read-only placeholder view of a variable.
   A `BFTaskCompletionSource` is a promise: it is a writable, single assignment container which sets the value of the future. (or an error - or cancels the task)
   The `BFTask` public interface remains read-only , hence it does not allow you to cancel it directly.
2. This has the same answer as the previous question: BFTask is read-only and represents a read-only value. Exposing cancellation tokens would allow you to manipulate the task, which is contradictory to its nature.
3. Let's take a look at it: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/blob/master/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationToken.m
   The `BFCancellationToken` token just stores a state, which the `BFTask` can check. Your async task code can basically regularly check `cancellationRequested` is set to true, which allows you to manually cancel your task.

   Note: The Bolts Framework iOS [docs](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) say: "A task is kind of like a JavaScript Promise" which can be confusing, because it really is a Future. I think it was just named wrong in its Javascript origins.

Answer (score 7):

There is a fairly useful implementation of cancellation tokens in Bolts, but for some reason it isn't documented at all outside of the header files. The key is the usage of the `BFCancellationTokenSource`. You need to keep a reference to the `BFCancellationTokenSource` in order to issue and cancel a `BFCancellationToken`.

In my example I have a particular function called `cancellableFunction()` that issues a bunch of tasks in succession. If the function is called again before the last call has completed, I want uncompleted tasks of the previous call to be cancelled.

The key here is to pass the `token` into each `continueWith` function call. If at any time the `token` is cancelled via the `tokenSource`, unreached `successBlock`s won't be executed. You can also check the status of cancellation via `task.cancelled` in each `BFContinuationBlock` (obviously will be false in success blocks).

Here is an example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   ...

   // instance reference to tokenSource so that it can be cancelled by any function in the ViewController
   var tokenSource: BFCancellationTokenSource?

   ...

   func cancellableFunction() -> BFTask {

      // First cancel the previous token
      tokenSource?.cancel()
      // Replace the previous TokenSource with a new one
      tokenSource = BFCancellationTokenSource()
      // Issue new Token from the new TokenSource
      let token = tokenSource!.token

      return functionThatReturnsBFTask().continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task:BFTask) -> AnyObject? in

         ...

         return nil
      }, cancellationToken: token).continueWithExecutor(BFExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), successBlock: { (task:BFTask) -> AnyObject? in

         ...

         return nil
      }, cancellationToken: token).continueWithBlock({ (task:BFTask) -> AnyObject? in

         // Here you can perform an actions you want to take on cancellation
         if task.cancelled {

         }

         ...

         return nil
      }, cancellationToken: token)
   }

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `[self.bfTaskCancelationToken cancel];` code to cancel series BFTask

**Register BFCancellationTokenSource**

```
self.bfTaskCancelationToken = [BFCancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource];
[self.bfTaskCancelationToken.token registerCancellationObserverWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"task hasbeen Cancelled.....");
    //Do stuff on cancelation task

} ];
```

**Implement Series BFTask**

Note: there is `cancellationToken:self.bfTaskCancelationToken.token` 
      code after `[task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)`

```
  [[[self showAlertProgressHud] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *taskLog) {


            BFTask *task = [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];
            for (int i=0; i<self.arrAssetPhotos.count; i++) {

                AIAssetPhoto *assetPhoto = self.arrAssetPhotos[i];
                task = [task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                    // Return a task that will be marked as completed.
                    return [self processOnAssetPhoto:assetPhoto index:i completion:NULL];
                } cancellationToken:self.bfTaskCancelationToken.token];

            }

            return task;


        }] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

            // all asset photos process are done.
            return nil;
        }];
```

**How to cancel continuous BFtask?**

```
  //just by calling one simple method 
  [self.bfTaskCancelationToken cancel];
```